# How to open classic version of OneNote in Windows 10?

Tags: start-menu, microsoft-onenote, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Office 2013 installed (with latest updates). I wanted to start OneNote so I clicked Start and then typed "onenote":

[image: Start search]

The first (and only) application that appeared is a new Windows 10 universal application (previously known as "Modern" version):

[image: Modern OneNote]

However, when I find Office 2013 folder in start menu there is also OneNote shortcut:

[image: Office 2013 folder]

Clicking it opens a classic version of OneNote, which I prefer:

[image: Classic OneNote]

How can I open the classic version only by typing something in the start-searchbox?

I even tried to delete the Modern version but Windows doesn't allow me to delete from `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`.

P.S. Screenshots are from Polish version of Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: I have both versions installed.  I am able to type in `OneNote` and it brings up both. I would try removing the desktop version then installing it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason repairing Office from original installer fixed the problem. Now two OneNote applications appear in start menu.